# Stack Layout Template

Tags: qt, templates, qml, stacklayout

I'm trying to write a Stack Layout template to be re-use in every page of my system.
May i know how can i edit or add index content to my page1 qml? The `Panel.qml` will use at my other pages with different tab button name.

**page1.qml as below:**

```
Panel {
    id: root      
  }
```

---

**Panel.qml**

RoundedPanel {
id: root
width: 1250
height: 960
color: "transparent"

```
default property alias content: stackLayout.data
property alias tabNames: navBar.buttonNames

NavigationBar {
    id: navBar
    parent: root
}

StackLayout {
    id: stackLayout
    height: parent.height
    width: root.width - navBar.width
    anchors.left: navBar.right
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    currentIndex: navBar.currentIndex
}
```

}

---

**NavigationBar.qml**

Item {
id: root
height: parent.height
width: 150
anchors.left: parent.left
anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

```
property var buttonNames: []
property int currentIndex: 0
```

RoundedPanel {
id: tabBar
width: parent.width + radius
height: parent.height
anchors.left: parent.left

```
    Column {
        id: buttonColumn
        topPadding: 80
        spacing: 1

        property alias indexTest: root.currentIndex

        Repeater {
            id: buttonRepeater
            model: root.buttonNames

            WidgetNavigationButton {
                text: buttonRepeater.model[index]
                checked: root.currentIndex == index
                onCheckedChanged: if (checked) { root.setCurrentIndex(index) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**NavigationButton.qml**

TabButton {
id: control
height: 75
width: 150

```
background: Rectangle {
    width: control.width
    height: control.height

    color: "transparent"
    border.width: Style.accentWidth
    border.color: Colors.accent
}

opacity: enabled ? (checked ? 1.0 : 0.25) : Style.disabledOpacity

contentItem: ButtonText {
    id: buttonText
    width: parent.width
    text: control.text
    font.weight: Font.Bold
    font.pointSize: 18
}
```

}

Comment: Since you are using 'default property' you can simply put items inside your `Panel`, or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: yes, my problem solved. thank you